# How to find a single RGB and opacity value from RGB values of a view against black and white backgrounds

Tags: ios, colors, rgb, opacity

I want to build a keyboard extension which looks similar to iPhone's native keyboard in both dark and light mode. However, I have a hard time finding the RGB and opacity values of keyboard keys that match iOS keyboard against both black and white backgrounds. I have pictures of the keyboard against light and dark background below. How can I find the RGB and opacity values given these two images? With color picker, I get that the color of keyboard keys against the light background is RGB(150, 150, 150) with opacity 1 and RGB(107, 107, 107) against the dark background with opacity 1. I need a single RGB and an opacity value so that under a light background it would be equivalent to RGB(150, 150, 150) and to RGB(107, 107, 107) under a dark background.

[image: white background]
[image: black background]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming grayscale colours with simple alpha compositing, let...

- Gc = gray level of composited result
- Gb = gray level of background
- Gk = gray level of keycap
- Ak = alpha level of keycap

then

- Gc = Gk + Gb * (1 - Ak)

(Here, Ae is assumed to be between 0 and 1.)

Now some known levels (as I measure in your screenshot):

For light mode,

- Gb = 106
- Gc = 150

For dark mode,

- Gb = 64
- Gc = 151

From that, we can derive:

- 150 = Gk + 106 * (1 - Ak)
- 106 = Gk + 43 * (1 - Ak)

From that, you can derive Ak:

- 150 - 106 = (106 - 43) * (1 - Ak)
- hence Ak = 0.3016

As a level from 1 to 255, Ak = 77.

And then you can derive Gk = 76.

Comment: nope, didn't work. This is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/OthHU7a

Comment: The background colours are a darker gray than what you showed earlier. That would affect how the keys appear. If it is simple alpha blending of grayscale tones, then Gc = Gk + Gb * (1 - Ak) should be correct.